# Neo4j get labels on an optional match

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following example cypher:

```
MATCH (n)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[:likes]->(p)
RETURN n, p, label(p)
```

This works great if optional match return a non null value. However if optional match is empty, this fails. Is there a way to return `label(p)` if p exists else return `null`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things, I think you probably want to narrow down what `n` matches with some criteria and an index, but to answer your question, `coalesce` is your friend.

```
MATCH (n)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[:likes]->(p)
RETURN n
, coalesce(p, 'nobody')
, coalesce(labels(p),'nothing')
```

Comment: Agree on narrowing down `n`